# Search DataRow with Linq and delete from Dataset

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, dataset, datarow

I want to delete a DataRow in my MySql database, using Linq to search the row, and delete the row from the dataSet.
But it wouldn't work to delete the row in my database.
My code:

```
var results = (from myRow in dataSet.Tables["Students_has_Courses"].AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<int>("Students_idStudents") == 1 && myRow.Field<int>("Courses_idCourses") == 1
              select new { id = myRow }).ToList();
foreach (var x in results)
{
        dataSet.Tables["Students_has_Courses"].Rows.Remove(x.id);
        x.id.Delete();
}

dataAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `....Rows.Remove(x);`?

Comment: Get some errors when I try that: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataRowCollection.Remove(System.Data.DataRow)' has some invalid arguments" && "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Removing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) rows from a DataTable means not that they will be deleted from the database later.

If you want them to be deleted with a DataAdapter/TableAdapter, you need to call [`Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the DataRow. Then they will be marked with [`DataRowState.Deleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx).

```
var results = from myRow in dataSet.Tables["Students_has_Courses"].AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<int>("Students_idStudents") == 1 
                 && myRow.Field<int>("Courses_idCourses")   == 1
              select myRow;
foreach (DataRow row in results)
    row.Delete();
dataAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```